# Rolling dice and Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, dice

I was doing a dice related calculation, while encountering this interesting problem.

Assuming I'm rolling 2 dice, and an outcome of 1 or 2 count as a success ($\lambda = 1/3\cdot2$). A **CDF** of poisson distribution at $k = 2$ gives a result of $0.9697878915060072$, but we all know it should add up to $1$ since there could be no other outcomes other than $0,1$ and $2$.

How did this happen?

p.s. If it helps, I get the CDF calculated using the function scipy.stats.poisson.cdf(2, 2/3)

Comment: *Dice* is plural

Comment: Why do you think this is Poisson?  A Poisson-distributed random variable takes infinitely many possible values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of Successes (1 or 2) when
rolling two fair dice independently. Then
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 2, p = 1/3).$
Then $P(X = k) = {2\choose k}(1/3)^k(2/3)^{2-k},$ for
$k = 0, 1, 2.$ You can make the table of this distribution
in R (ignore row numbers in brackets [ ]).

```
k = 0:2;  PDF = dbinom(k,2,1/3)
cbind(k, PDF)
     k       PDF
[1,] 0 0.4444444   # 4/9
[2,] 1 0.4444444   # 4/9
[3,] 2 0.1111111   # 1/9
```

Also, $E(X) = np = 2/3 = 0(4/9) + 1(4/9) + 2(1/9).$

There are useful instances in which a Poisson
distribution with the same mean as a binomial
distribution gives a close approximation to the binomial distribution. But this is not such an
instance.

If $Y \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=2/3),$
then the distribution table for $Y$ is shown below. Its probabilities are quite different from those
in the distribution of $X$ above.

```
k=0:8;  PDF = round(dpois(k, 2/3), 5)
cbind(k, PDF)
      k     PDF
 [1,] 0 0.51342
 [2,] 1 0.34228
 [3,] 2 0.11409
 [4,] 3 0.02535
 [5,] 4 0.00423
 [6,] 5 0.00056
 [7,] 6 0.00006
 [8,] 7 0.00001
 [9,] 8 0.00000  # subsequent probabilities
                 # smaller than 0.000005
```

Along with @saulspatz, I wonder what a Poisson
distribution has to do with this.  Was there
another question beyond computing the probability
distribution of $X?$

**Addendum** per Comments: on Poisson approximation to Binomial distributions. Especially if $n$ is large and $p$ is small, Poisson approximations to Binomial distributions may be useful: Consider $\mathsf{Binom}(n=200, p=.02)$ with mean 4, and $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda =4).$

```
x = 0:10
pdf.b = round(dbinom(x,200,.02), 4)
pdf.p = round(dpois(x, 4), 4)
cbind(x, pdf.b, pdf.p)
       x  pdf.b  pdf.p
 [1,]  0 0.0176 0.0183
 [2,]  1 0.0718 0.0733
 [3,]  2 0.1458 0.1465
 [4,]  3 0.1963 0.1954
 [5,]  4 0.1973 0.1954
 [6,]  5 0.1579 0.1563
 [7,]  6 0.1047 0.1042
 [8,]  7 0.0592 0.0595
 [9,]  8 0.0292 0.0298
[10,]  9 0.0127 0.0132
[11,] 10 0.0049 0.0053
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now I do realize there's something improper to using Poi in this case. However I still have some confusion: I choose to using Poi since it tells me the probability of successes in a given time interval, and since dice rollings are independent, I interpret rolling n dice as roll one dice n times. Why is it not fine seeing "in n dice rolls" as the time interval and using the poisson distribution to calculate?

Comment: One clue not to model successes as Poisson that the only possible numbers of successes are 0, 1, and 2. Poisson random variables take integer values $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, \dots ,$ where there is no theoretical largest possible value. In practice, values beyond some point have such small probabilities as to be 'impossible' for practical purposes. As in my example of POIS(2/3) above, it would be extremely rare to see values above 8 (not _impossible,_ but very unlikely). By contrast, the dist'n BINOM(n, p), can take _only_ values $0,1,2,3,\dots,,n.$ Values above $n$ simply can't ever happen.

Comment: Got it. So on the contrary, does that mean when n gets very large, I can approximate Bino using Poi?

Comment: Yes. See Addendum to my Answer. I did not search for a really good approximation, but this one will give you an idea how it works. Two or three place agreement for this example.

Comment: Thanks for your help!